# Некорректно отображаются символы

Tags: java, windows, selenium, unicode

Всем привет! Ситуация такая: я сделал jar-файл для selenium (скрипт для автозаполнения), который считывает данные из .csv и записывает эти данные в поля на сайте. Данные в .csv на немецком языке. 
   Суть проблемы: на моей локальной машине всё проходит отлично, но если скрипт запускать на немецкой машине, то вместо характерных умлаутов (ü, ö, ä, ß) отображаются кракозябры. Пробовал менять кодировку в csv с помощью notepad++(на UTF-8, на ISO 8859-1) ничего не помогает. 
    Усугубляется всё тем, что некоторые xPath-локаторы тоже с умлаутами (например id="öfter", из-за чего скрипт падает, т.к. элементы с такими локаторами не находятся. 
    Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно поправить

Comment: можно попробовать запустить с флагом java -jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF8

Comment: @Vlad Mamaev большое спасибо!
Проблема с заполнением полей ушла. Осталась проблема с xpath-локаторами с умлаутами, они по прежнему ищутся с кракозябрами